# Guacamole connect to windows server black desktop

Tags: windows, guacamole

All RDP sessions in Guacamole (to a Windows host) suffer from a black desktop/background. This is due to the RDP client connection not specifiying that the desktop wallpaper should be displayed. If you do a native RDP client connection you just specify a "LAN" experience setting and this lets Windows know that there is enough bandwidth to display the desktop wallpaper. But with Guacamole this "LAN/experience" setting is not passed up to the user-mapping.xml file, so there is no way to easily set it directly from within Guacamole.
Any thoughts on how to work around the issue, and present Guacamole users with nice colorful desktops instead of ... black ones ?

I see this problem [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/guacamole/discussion/1110834/thread/dde452d3/?limit=25),I also have this problem,anyone have idea??

thanks

Comment: Is add RDP performance/experience flags in 0.9.8?? it's not working at 0.9.6??

Answer (score 1):

Change the IP from 10.x.x.x to your servers IP. this works for windows 10 and enables desktop and TLS for the RDP session

```
    <connection name="Win10 Desktop">
      <protocol>rdp</protocol>
      <param name="hostname">10.x.x.x</param>
       <param name="ignore-cert">true</param>
       <param name="color-depth">24</param>
       <param name="security">tls</param>
       <param name="enable-wallpaper">true</param>
      <param name="port">3389</param>
    </connection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that `enable-wallpaper` parameter for your RDP connection is set to `true`.

Just add:

```
<enable-wallpaper>true</enable-wallpaper>
```

to the section of your connection in your *user-mappings.xml* file.

Further information is available at [the documentation for setting up RDP connections](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#rdp).